# IPTables NAT and virtual interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, iptables, nat

I have 2 VM's running CentOS 7 with the following `ifconfig` configurations:

```
VM1: ifconfig
eth0: public ip
eth0:0: LAN IP 172.22.xx.x1

VM2: ifconfig
eth0: no public ip
eth0:0: LAN IP 172.22.xx.x2
```

And I want `VM2` to be able to access the internet. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

I've tried every combination of `iptables` `POSTROUTING, PREROUTING, FORWARD, DNAT, SNET` and `route` you can think of to no avail. I must be doing something wrong.

Does anyone have a simple example of how to achieve this?

To test `VM2` external access, I am pinging `www.google.com` (and IP) -- but getting unknown host and 100% packet loss respectively.

**EDIT - More info**

Running `tcpdump -nni eth0:0 icmp` on `VM1` and `ping 8.8.8.8` on `VM2` yields the following results:

```
09:28:05.957841 IP VM2 private ip > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 13950, seq 6, length 64
09:28:05.957900 IP VM1 public ip > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 13950, seq 6, length 64
09:28:05.959157 IP 8.8.8.8 > VM1 public ip: ICMP echo reply, id 13950, seq 6, length 64
09:28:05.959172 IP 8.8.8.8 > VM2 private ip: ICMP echo reply, id 13950, seq 6, length 64
```

But `VM2` doesn't receive the packets. Here is my `iptables` script for `VM1`:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

# Flush tables
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0:0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
service iptables restart
```

And `route` for `VM2`:

```
route add default gw <VM1 private ip>
```

**EDIT 2 - More info**

`VM2 route`:

```
[travis@VM2 ~]$ sudo route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.22.20.195   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.22.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
```

And `VM1 iptables`:

```
[travis@VM1 ~]$ sudo iptables -vnL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 3039 packets, 651K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination        

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 88 packets, 6598 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination        
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0:0 eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0          

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2602 packets, 304K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination        

[travis@VM1 ~]$ sudo iptables -t nat -vnL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 114 packets, 9000 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination        

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 81 packets, 6692 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination        

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 167 packets, 10845 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination        

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination        
  200 13153 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: It may be the problem can't be addressed with iptables, rather you may need to set up bridging.  How is your VM Host set up (and are you able to ping it from the VM Clients)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. All VMs sit under the same LAN `172.22.xx.xx` and can ping each other.

Comment: If you do a continuous ping from your client and tcpdump on each of the virtual and actual interfaces on the VM Host, what traffic do you see ?  Is the gateway correctly set on the VM clients ?

Comment: Gateway is set to `route add default gw host`. `tcpdump -nni eth0:0 icmp` on `VM Host` and `ping host` (host is hostname) on `VM client` shows successful pings in `tcpdump`. Doing a `ping google.com` from `VM client` yields nothing and a `ping 8.8.8.8` shows up in `VM Host tcpdump`, but 100% packet loss on `VM Client`. Does this indicate that the `icmp` replies are not being forwarded back to `VM Client`? I have `ip_forward` set to `1`. See OP for more details..

Comment: What do you mean by  "host" when you say route add default gw host. Really, when working with a routing table you should be doing everything by IP address.  Can you provide the output of 'route -n'  and confirm the IP address of your VM server.    Also, lets check your iptables rules - whats the output of 'iptables -t nat -vnL' .  Looking at additional things, why do you have eth0:0 - this would not seem to make sense in the default configuaraion (and a tcpdump command should be run on the underlying interface, not virtual interface, eg tcpdump -n eth0).... cont

Comment: For the outgoing packets, what source address do they have on the tcpdump ? (This will tell us if NAT is working correctly).

Comment: Sorry, `host` is the alias for the `IP`, defined in my hosts file. Using `eth0:0` as that's the interface with the local IP. Posted more details in OP.

Comment: I think the problem relates to your usage of eth0:0 - this implies a virtual interface on the host - but I would imagine you need a bridged interface.

Comment: How would I go about bridging the interfaces? Would I need to set up a dummy interface for `eth0:0` and then bridge them?

Comment: When you ping 8.8.8.8 from VM2, are you sure VM2 does not receive the reply? Perhaps it does,but it is discarded. Could you please confirm this by running tcpdump on VM2 as you ping 8.8.8.8? Tcpdump intercepts packets before anything else on a machine, and packets appear even if later they are discarded by the firewall, by reverse packet filtering, and so on...

Comment: And, BTW, when you bring up your fireall, you will also need `iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0:0 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT` which is the reverse of what you already have.

Comment: Added the new `iptable` rule and ran `tcpdump` on `VM2`... Still only shows requests outbound and no replies coming in, even though `VM1` seems to be forwarding the packets on.

Comment: You should turn off reverse pack filtering on VM2. Edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and change the value of `net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=1` to `0`.